# what is the value of $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}$?

Tags: polynomials

if we have $a+b+c=1$ and $ab+bc+ac=\frac{1}{3}$ then what is the value of $$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}$$

and

$$\frac{a}{b+1}+\frac{b}{c+1}+\frac{c}{a+1}$$.

from the hypothesis we have also $a^2 +b^2 +c^2 =\frac{1}{3}$ and also we have $a^3 +b^3+c^3=3abc$ but I don't know how should get the result. it will be great if you share your Idea with me,thanks.

Comment: Open $(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)$ might help.

Comment: what kind of numbers are $a,b,c$?

Comment: they are real numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:since
$$a+b+c=1,ab+bc+ac=\dfrac{1}{3}$$ so 
$$(a+b+c)^2-3(ab+bc+ac)=0\Longrightarrow (a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2=0\Longrightarrow  a=b=c$$

Comment: (+1) Exactly. Equality of $a,b,c$ can also be derived from Newton's inequalities. It is important to notice that $a+b+c$ and $ab+ac+bc$ are symmetric polynomials while $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}$ is not a symmetric function.